# Google Guice Autowiring for Factory

Tags: guice, autowired

Please explain the correct way to auto-wire using Google-Guice in the following scenario where factory is used.I am using XML factory for XSLT processing.

```
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
TransformerFactory xmlTransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
CustomUriResolver out = new CustomUriResolver(new HashMap<String, StringWriter>());
xmlTransformerFactory.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/outputURIResolver", out );
Transformer xmlTransfomer = xmlTransformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("src/main/resources/test.xslt"));
xmlTransfomer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xml)), new StreamResult(strWriter));
System.out.println(out.getResults().size());
for( Map.Entry resultEntry : out.getResults().entrySet() ){
    System.out.println(resultEntry.getValue());
};
```

Should I have to auto-wire Transformer factory , which requires custom URI resolver.Also this piece of code is part of API which will keep receiving requests and process it.But then it has to call newTransformer() for every request it receives.

Comment: Do you need a new transformer each time or do you want the transformer to be available through guice as a singleton throughout your application?

Comment: I need it as singleton.. I can use the same instance for all the requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do this is to simply let Guice handle the dependency for you. How you create your dependency is up to you - guice doesn't care (unless you must use interceptors where guice needs to create the dependency for you.

For this case, I would use a provider to inject my dependencies. Essentially you'll want to extract all creation logic out, so that it is executed once to store your transformer and then inject that transformer everywhere. The reason I am using a provider is so that I can inject more dependencies into it (you can do the same by annotating a method as provider I believe).

See this example:

```
public class TransformerProvider implements Provider<Transformer> {

        @Inject
        @Named("output.uri.resolver")
        String outputUriResolver;

        @Inject
        @Named("xslt.location")
        String xsltLocation;

        Transformer instance = null;

        @Override
        public Transformer get() {
            if(instance == null) {
                try {
                    instance = create();
                } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }

        private Transformer create() throws TransformerConfigurationException {
            System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
                            "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
            TransformerFactory xmlTransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            CustomUriResolver out = new CustomUriResolver(new HashMap<String, StringWriter>());
            xmlTransformerFactory.setAttribute(outputUriResolver, out );
            return xmlTransformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltLocation));
        }
    }
```

This class acts as a provider for your Transformer. It initiates it the first time it is required and will store the instance for you. Alternatively you can construct it in the constructor as well.

I am injecting the 2 common properties (uri resolver and the location of the xslt). The latter at the very least might make it easier to test your application (just inject a different xslt into the provider to test it?).

Then I need to bind it in any module so that Guice knows about it and can use it:

```
Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Transformer.class).toProvider(TransformerProvider.class).in(Singleton.class); // bind factory
            }
        });
```

I am binding the Type to its provider in a singleton. That means that only 1 instance of that provider will be used throughout your application.

Alternatively you can do either of those 2 options as well:

1. Bind the transformer in your module. Essentially put all the creation code into a module in guice and then bind the created Transformer as a singleton.
2. Create a provider method. This is simply an annotated method in the Guice Module that will return a Transformer for you.

All of them essentially solve the same issue: Have an instance of the XMLTransformer ready in your application for injection.

I hope that's what you're looking for,

Artur

Comment: Sorry for the late response..This worked well..What if i need more than one instance of transformer with different vales for uriresolver and xslt location

Comment: In that case you would use assisted inject and provide your location and resolver to the factory before creation. You can then cache your transformers based on those values so you don't have to create them over and over. You can read about assisted inject here: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject